# Segmentation fault Netbeans 7.1 C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, segmentation-fault

I want to build and run my project in Netbeans. I generated a simple class (nothing edited) and did run it.

This is what was shown in the output:

```
make: *** [.validate-impl] Segmentation fault
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:90: recipe for target `.validate-impl' failed


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 678ms)
```

I already installed Cygwin and the C++ compiler is set.

I hope you could help me!

Comment: Are you on windows? If yes from where come your make, MinGW?

Comment: @alain.janinm I'm using windows, but i don't understand your question! I did nothing with MiniGW as far as i know to be honest. Maybe that is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to not have the binary needed to execute make.

Try this :

> install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Then :

> In netbeans go to Tools --> options
>
> Go in C/C++ pane, and here set your g++ compiler (you find it in the install directory of above tools) and your make command

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, I already installed Cygwin and the C++ compiler is set.

Comment: ok, and you properly set the make command to? I don't see anything else, you can find a good tuto for that here http://royalexander.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/configuring-cygwin-cc-compiler-for-netbeans-65-under-windows/ its for 6.5 but config is the same thing ;)

Comment: I made a screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/cppd.png/ maybe you see what is wrong

Comment: Seems perfect... I don't know what to say maybe try with MSYS

Comment: My problem is solved! My Virus Scanner blocked 'make'. Thank you for your time and your help!

Comment: I don't even know it was a possible issue :/